# Undefined method if @admin.save

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a really strange error, when i submit my form to create a new admin i get this error:

```
NoMethodError in AdminsController#create
undefined method `admin?' for #<Admin:0x6c7f098>
```

in line:

```
if @admin.save
```

How is this error produced? I mainly used scaffold code and i only deletet the views of the controller! Here is my controller: I thank everybody for help!

```
class AdminsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_admin, only: [ :edit, :update, :destroy]



  # GET /admins/new
  def new
    @admin = Admin.new
  end

  # GET /admins/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /admins
  # POST /admins.json
  def create
    @admin = Admin.new(admin_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @admin.save
        format.html { redirect_to adminpage_index_path, notice: 'Admin was successfully created.' }
      else
        redirect_to adminpage_index_path
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /admins/1
  # PATCH/PUT /admins/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @admin.update(admin_params)
        format.html { redirect_to adminpage_index_path , notice: 'Admin was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        redirect_to adminpage_index_path
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /admins/1
  # DELETE /admins/1.json
  def destroy
    @admin.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to adminpage_index_path }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_admin
      @admin = Admin.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def admin_params
      params.require(:admin).permit(:username, :vorname, :nachname, :strasse, :ort, :plz, :telefon, :handy, :email, :password, :password_confirmation)
    end
end
```

Comment: I'm guessing there's something in the model causing this problem. Look very closely at the stack trace to find the offending line and the context where it's called. You're looking for a reference to the method `admin?` which isn't in your code here.

Comment: Which line is causing the issue? admin = Admin.new(admin_params) or admin.save ?

Comment: it says admin.save! I will look into my model and report you more

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I can see, your Admin model probably does not inherit from ActiveRecord::Base. Make sure it does. The model should look like this:

```
class Admin < ActiveRecord::Base
  # ...
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Your admin model has a callback of some kind.  i.e. before_save, after_save, after_validations.  Something like that that is trying to call admin?

Post admin.rb file and the stack trace of the error and this should be easy to find.